# SwiftUI: The Picker label text is not appearing and I can't seem to modify it

Tags: swift, swiftui, label, picker

When I create a menu style picker I am only seeing the picker options displayed and not my label text.

This is using the updated code: Picker(selection:, content:, label), but I get the same result when using the deprecated for versions code as well: Picker(selection:, label:, content)

This is my Code:

```
    private var addGenderSection: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            Spacer()
            
            Text("What's your gender?")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                .foregroundStyle(.white)
            
            Picker(selection: $gender) {
                Text("1").tag(1)
                Text("2").tag(2)
            } label: {
                Text("Select a gender")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .foregroundStyle(.purple)
                    .frame(height: 55)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background(Color.white)
            }
            .pickerStyle(.menu)

            
            Spacer()
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding(30)
    }
```

This is my result:

[image]

Expected result:

Not Selected:

[image]

Selected:

[image]

Comment: you could try using `Form {  Picker(selection: $gender) ... }`. Try also using a `Menu`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @workingdog said, `Menu` is a better solution in this circumstance.
Actually, you can't customize the `pickerStyle(.menu)` appearance. Try this:

```swift
private var genders = [1, 2]
@State private var gender: Int?

...
Menu {
    Button("\(genders[0])") {
        gender = 1
    }
    Button("\(genders[1])") {
        gender = 2
    }
} label: {
    Text(gender == nil ? "Select a gender" : "Gender is \(gender!)")
        .foregroundColor(.purple)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
}
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
.background {
    Color.white
        .frame(height: 55)
        .cornerRadius(10)
}
```

[image]